# How to get more information about a failed Azure deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to automatically deploy a resource of type Microsoft.BotService/botServices on Azure and the deployment gets stuck endlessly retrying it while only giving me a "Internal server error (500)" message.

Is there any way to get more specific information?

Comment: Please check the audit logs. You should be able to find more information there.

Comment: Checked those. It shows that what failed was "Write a bot service" and then in the JSON details:

"statusMessage": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"InternalServerError\",\"message\":\"Encountered internal server error. Please try again.\"}}"

Answer (score 0):

Click on the resource group you're deploying to in the Portal.

[image: Resource group overview]

Comment: I did. That's where I found the "Internal server error (500)" part.